# What is the HX711 measuring?

Tags: adc, hx711

I've read [the library for the HX711 Avia Semiconductor](https://github.com/bogde/HX711/blob/master/src/HX711.cpp), and I don't understand the `read()` function.

From what I can tell, the other functions use `read()` to result in the final mass measured by the scale by averaging `read()`, subtracting the offset, and finally dividing by the factor. But what is `read()` really reading? Is it directly reading the voltage (between INA+ and INA-)? If so, what are the units?

[Datasheet for HX711](https://image.dfrobot.com/image/data/SEN0160/hx711_english.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

In the code, `read()` just performs a 24-bit read, in counts of the chip's 24-bit ADC. According to the chip's datasheet:

> Channel A
> can be programmed with a gain of 128 or 64,
> corresponding to a full-scale differential input
> voltage of ±20mV or ±40mV respectively, when
> a 5V supply is connected to AVDD analog power
> supply pin. Channel B has a fixed gain of 32.

Based on this, the measurement is the voltage across the bridge, with channel A full-scale being 20 mV or 40 mV depending on the PGA, and channel B reading full-scale when the differential input is 80 mV (based on the indicated gains).

Given that the 24-bit scale spans between -524288 counts and 524287 counts, the voltage per count is around 38, 76, or 153 nV depending on the channel and gain.